# Error adding "Like" button on personal web site

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-like

Constantly getting the following error after implementing the "Like" button:

You failed to provide a valid list of administators. You need to supply the administors using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Mark Rapp: compare arrangement with Isfahan original" />
<meta property="og:type" content="musician" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.markrapp.com/bradenrapp/isfahan.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.markrapp.com/images/markrapp.gif" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Mark Rapp web site" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="544808239" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Compare Mark Rapp's arrangement with Billy Strayhorn's Isfahan original" />
```

... and then in the page...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=114617051955611&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.markrapp.com" send="false" width="300" show_faces="false" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
```

So, it seems to render fine, but clicking on the "like" button results in a message that reads "You like this." And then beside it an error link which refers to the message above. Furthermore, it does not reflect that I "liked" the page n my Facebook profile.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Additionally, if I strip out all the meta open-graph tags and just use this: 

<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
        style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>

It posts to my facebook wall, but gives me another error.

Comment: You need to be specific. What error?